# Something wrong with enqueueing bootstrap in functions.php (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. This is it so far:

```
function reg_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrapstylemin', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrapstyleresmin', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css' );}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'reg_scripts');

function wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery(){

wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-scriptes', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js', array('bootstrap-jquery'));

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery' );
```

[I am sorry, there is a screenshot of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVaGH.png)

After I saw this errors, I removed the CDN's, but still not working.

Comment: you havent stated what is wrong either so not much anyone can do for you. Did you check the console for errors? ie. 404 on the files?#

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
function reg_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrapstylemin', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '3.4.6' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrapstyleresmin', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css', array(), '1.0.0' );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'reg_scripts');

function wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery(){

wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-scriptes', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js', array('bootstrap-jquery'), '3.4.6', false);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery' );
```